# how to add date in Teradata?

Tags: date, teradata

Hi i want to add 01/01/1970 to a column ,datatype of last_hit_time_gmt is bigint ,when i run the below query i am getting data type

> last_hit_gmmt

does not match a defined datatype name.

```
   select 
    distinct STG.OMN_APND_KEY,
    STG.last_hit_time_gmt,
    IIF(STG.last_hit_time_gmt  <>0,ADD_TO_DATE(TO_DATE('01/01/1970', 'DD/MM/YYYY'),'SS',cast(STG.last_hit_time_gmt as DATE ),NULL) 
from    EDW_STAGE_CDM_SRC.STG_OMNITUREDATA STG
 WHERE
 UPPER(STG_OMNITUREDATA.EVAR41) IN 
('CONS_SUPP: CONSUMER','STORE','PURCHASE')  and 
STG.OMN_APND_KEY='61855975'
```

please help me..

Comment: Your use if IIF() is either pseudo-code or code for different RDBMS. I don't believe Teradata supports IIF().

Comment: Thanks Rob so should i use case statement... if so please can you write that...and how do u convert that column to date

Answer (score 0):

The query and data type is incompatible with Teradata.

- As stated in the comments you may want to use "CASE" instead of "IFF". The general format is

```
CASE WHEN *condition* THEN *result_if_true*
 ELSE *result_if_false*
END as *ColumnName*
```

*editing based on comment response*

So in your query example the case statement can be used like...

```
    select distinct STG.OMN_APND_KEY
     ,STG.last_hit_time_gmt
     ,CASE WHEN STG.last_hit_time_gmt = 0 THEN NULL 
       ELSE DATE '1970-01-01'
      END AS YourColName
    FROM EDW_STAGE_CDM_SRC.STG_OMNITUREDATA STG
    WHERE UPPER(STG_OMNITUREDATA.EVAR41) IN 
    ('CONS_SUPP: CONSUMER','STORE','PURCHASE')  and 
    STG.OMN_APND_KEY='61855975'
```

Also, if you are merely just trying to update the field STG.last_hit_time_gmt, why not just use two simple **UPDATE** statements?

```
    UPDATE EDW_STAGE_CDM_SRC.STG_OMNITUREDATA 
     SET STG.last_hit_time_gmt = DATE '1970-01-01'
    WHERE STG.last_hit_time_gmt <>  0
     AND UPPER(STG_OMNITUREDATA.EVAR41) IN 
        ('CONS_SUPP: CONSUMER','STORE','PURCHASE')  
     AND STG.OMN_APND_KEY='61855975';

    UPDATE EDW_STAGE_CDM_SRC.STG_OMNITUREDATA 
     SET STG.last_hit_time_gmt = NULL
    WHERE STG.last_hit_time_gmt =  0
     AND UPPER(STG_OMNITUREDATA.EVAR41) IN 
        ('CONS_SUPP: CONSUMER','STORE','PURCHASE')  
     AND STG.OMN_APND_KEY='61855975';
```

Comment: i am trying to add here the date 01/01/1970 to the column last_hit_gmmt if the column value last_hit_gmmt is not equal to 0 if it is 0 then value is populated as NULL...