# How to convert a column in seconds to dateformat in Teradata?

Tags: date, teradata

I have a column which is of bigint datatype(in seconds) which should be added to a date, so i need to convert this column into dateformat.

Answer (score 1):

The arithmetic must be done against a timestamp data type in Teradata. The date data type does not have a time element associated with it. The following SQL should help point you in the right direction:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(1234 AS BIGINT) AS INTERVAL SECOND(4)) AS Seconds_
     , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0) AS CurrentTimestamp_
     , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + Seconds_ AS NewTimeStamp
```

Answer (score 1):

If the number of seconds is less than 864000000 you can simply use interval arithmetic:

```
CAST(col AS TIMESTAMP) + (bigintcol * INTERVAL '0000 00:00:01' DAY TO SECOND)
```

Based on your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33911820/how-to-add-date-in-teradata) your input is a Unixtime, those are two functions for converting them from/to Teradata timestamps:

```
/**********
Converting Unix/POSIX time to a Timestamp 

Unix time: Number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC not counting leap seconds (currently 24 in 2011)

Also working for negative numbers.
The maximum range of Timestamps is based on the range of INTEGERs:
1901-12-13 20:45:52 (-2147483648) to 2038-01-19 03:14:07 (2147483647)

Can be changed to use BIGINT instead of INTEGER

20101211 initial version - Dieter Noeth
**********/

REPLACE FUNCTION UnixTime_to_TimeStamp (UnixTime INT)
RETURNS TimeStamp(0)
LANGUAGE SQL
CONTAINS SQL
DETERMINISTIC
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COLLATION INVOKER
INLINE TYPE 1
RETURN 
CAST(DATE '1970-01-01' + (UnixTime / 86400) AS TIMESTAMP(0))
+ ((UnixTime MOD 86400) * INTERVAL '00:00:01' HOUR TO SECOND)
;

SELECT
   UnixTime_to_TimeStamp(-2147483648)
  ,UnixTime_to_TimeStamp(0)
  ,UnixTime_to_TimeStamp(2147483647)
;


/**********
Converting a Timestamp to Unix/POSIX time

Unix time: Number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC not counting leap seconds (currently 24 in 2011)

The maximum range of Timestamps is based on the range of INTEGERs:
1901-12-13 20:45:52 (-2147483648) to 2038-01-19 03:14:07 (2147483647)

Can be changed to use BIGINT instead of INTEGER

20101211 initial version - Dieter Noeth
**********/
REPLACE FUNCTION TimeStamp_to_UnixTime (ts TimeStamp(6))
RETURNS INTEGER
LANGUAGE SQL
CONTAINS SQL
DETERMINISTIC
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COLLATION INVOKER
INLINE TYPE 1
RETURN 
(CAST(ts AS DATE) - DATE '1970-01-01') * 86400
+ (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ts) * 3600)
+ (EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM ts) * 60)
+ (EXTRACT(SECOND FROM ts))
;

SELECT
   TimeStamp_to_UnixTime(TIMESTAMP '1901-12-13 20:45:52')
  ,TimeStamp_to_UnixTime(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
  ,TimeStamp_to_UnixTime(TIMESTAMP '2038-01-19 03:14:07')
;
```